Does the bid quantity correspond entirely to the quoted bid price?
My TD easy web broker shows the bid price and the number of bids.
However, should I assume that the bid price is the same for the number of bids.
For example, the bid price is $0.5 and there are 5 bids listed.
Can I assume that all 5 bids are $0.5 or the bid price listed is the current bid, which implies the other 4 bids could be the same or different?

If the bid as shown as $0.50 for 5 shares, this means that there are traders willing to buy a total of 5 shares at that price, and there is no one willing to buy at a higher price (at least on the exchange being quoted). The 5 shares could be a single order or multiple orders, but it refers to the amount of demand at the highest price of unfilled buy orders (bid price). Buy orders at lower prices are not shown in this type of quote.

The NBBO quote represents a compilation of the highest bid and the lowest ask from all of the exchanges.  The volume number represents the number of shares being bid or asked at the respective prices.
For example, if the quote is 600 $25.00 x $25.10 200 it means that there are one or more buyers for 600 shares at $25.00 and one or more sellers for 200 shares at $25.10.  The volume number does not represent the number of bids.
